# HTML page is not displayed correctly in JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, css, swing, jeditorpane

I have a spring boot application which displays a `JFrame` when an event is triggered. The frame displays the HTML page but the issue I am facing here is that when I am opening HTML page manually it's displayed correctly in chrome browser just like this:

[image: Browser View]

But when I am trying to open the same page in the frame via my application it's looking like this:

[image: Jframe View]

I have tried but couldn't figure out what's the issue. Below is the code to display frame:

```
public class BringUpFrame {

    static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BringUpFrame.class);
    private static final int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    private static final int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    private static final int TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;
    private static final HWND HWND_TOPMOST = new HWND(Pointer.createConstant(-1));
    private static JFrame frmOpt;
    static String Message;

    public static JFrame ShowBanner() throws IOException {

        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        String ScrnResol = getScreenResolution();
        String[] ScreenResolution = ScrnResol.split(",");

        try {
            width = Integer.parseInt(ScreenResolution[0]);
            height = Integer.parseInt(ScreenResolution[0]);

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            logger.info("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
        }

        HWND windowHandle = User32Ext.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
        frmOpt = new JFrame("Banner");
        frmOpt.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frmOpt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frmOpt.setUndecorated(true);
        frmOpt.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f));
        frmOpt.setVisible(true);
        frmOpt.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
        frmOpt.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        bringToForeground(getHWND(frmOpt), windowHandle);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
        jEditorPane.setEditable(false);
        URL url = BringUpFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.htm");

        try {
            jEditorPane.setPage(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            jEditorPane.setContentType("text/html");
            jEditorPane.setText("<html>Page not found.</html>");
        }

        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jEditorPane);
        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        panel.add(jScrollPane);

        frmOpt.add(panel);
        frmOpt.pack();
        frmOpt.setVisible(true);

        return frmOpt;

    }

    public static void disposeBanner() {
        frmOpt.dispose();
    }

    private static void bringToForeground(HWND clientWindow, HWND tillHandle) {
        User32Ext.INSTANCE.SetWindowPos(clientWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
    }

    private static HWND getHWND(Component comp) {
        return new HWND(Native.getComponentPointer(comp));
    }

    public static String getScreenResolution() {

        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();

        String resolution = width + "," + height;
        logger.info("Till Resolution is (width,height) : " + resolution);
        return resolution;

    }

}
```

**test.htm:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    font-size: 72px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.00;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
}

.Message-Line {
    width: 50%;
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #cc3333;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:25%;
}

h2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.14;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
}

.contact {
    width: 100%;
    height: 28px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.17;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
}

.footer {
    width: 745px;
    height: 140px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #fbefef;
    margin-top:15%;
    margin-left:25%;
    margin-right:25%;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Dashboard-unavailable</h1>
    <p class="Message-Line"></p>
    <h2>Please use another dashboard instead</h2>
    <div class="footer">
        <h3 class="contact">
            Please contact the Helpdesk quoting code:<b>{{XYZ}}</b>
        </h3>
        <h3 class="contact">
            dashboard number: <b>{{1234}}</b>
        </h3>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone please help me with this ?

Regards,
Manish

Comment: Swing's support for HTML/CSS is poor. It supports a **sub-set** of **HTML *3.2*** and ignores many CSS properties. Either simplify the HTML / CSS or use a more powerful component (e.g. the Java-FX `WebView`) to display the page.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am able to display the webpge properly using webview as suggested by you. Only thing that is pending that webview is not displayed completely over the screen like the jframe and also I don't want to display taskbar and title bar while displaying webpage

Comment: Umm ... OK. Not sure what you expect/want from me at this point. Note that beyond knowing that the `WebView` will embed an actual browser in a Java component, I've not dealt with it. Consult the Java Docs and any tutorial on it, and if that does not help solve the latest problems, ask a new question tagging Java-FX. I expect the experts in same will advise you to start again with pure Java-FX - easier to code & debug than a mix of the two.